# Is there a coordinate system for the Schwarzchild spacetime where $r$ is proper length/time?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

I don't see any when I search online.  The way I would try to construct them would be as follows.  Starting from the standard metric

$$ds^2 = -\left(1 - \frac{r_s}{r'}\right)dt^2 + \left(1-\frac{r_s}{r'}\right)^{-1}dr'^2 + r'^2\left(d\theta^2 + \sin^2\theta d\phi^2\right)$$

(where I've called it $r'$ instead so as to reserve $r$ for the new proper-length coordinate), we know we want $g_{rr} = \pm 1$.  Let's start from the region inside the horizon, $0 \lt r' \lt r_s$, and integrate the proper length along a radial coordinate line.  We need the lengths to match in both systems, hence

$$\left(\frac{r_s}{r'} - 1\right)^{-\frac12} dr' = 1dr.$$

($r$ is timelike here so I just threw away the minus sign on both sides and took the square root to make it length) which according to Wolfram integrates to

$$\left.\left(-r'\sqrt{\frac{r_s}{r'}-1}-r_s\tan^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{r_s}{r'}-1}\right)\right|_0^{r'} = r$$

which after plugging in zero on the left becomes

$$-r'\sqrt{\frac{r_s}{r'}-1} + r_s\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \tan^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{r_s}{r'}-1}\right) = r.$$

So that's great, but the problem is we need to invert that equation and get $r'$ as a function of $r$ instead, so that we can write $g_{tt}$, $g_{\theta\theta}$, and $g_{\phi\phi}$ as functions of $r$.  And I don't know how to do that.  Can anyone help or let me know if there's a site that already has the formula for such a coordinate system?

Comment: I think the possibility you presented is the only one available if you do not want to introduce a new time coordinate at the same time. This would, in itself, yield a different foliation of the spacetime manifold and the hypersurfaces would be different - you wouldn't measure spatial lengths within the $t_{Schwarzschild}=const$ hypersurfaces anymore. If you want to keep the hypersurfaces, your construction is the only option. The $r'$ in your equation is defined implicitly and I see no chance of inverting the relation through elementary functions. Have you tried inspecting it for monotonicity?

Comment: @K.T.  Thanks, that's helpful.  I plugged it into Desmos just now and it is monotonic (as it ought to be, being the integral of pure proper time) other than apparently having an infinite derivative at $r_s$.  As to re-foliating, I assume that would make the metric no longer static, correct?  In which case I think, as you say, that I wouldn't want to do that either.  I appreciate your input.

Comment: The metric itself is static - that is independent of coordinates, as there exists a Killing vector $K=\partial_{t}$, for which $\mathcal{L}_{K}g = 0$, which is orthogonal to the hypersurfaces of constant t / surface-forming $K^\wedge dK=0$. The $K$ in the last equation is supposed to be interpreted as dual to vector field K under the musical isomorphism. What I think you mean is that in new coordinates, $\partial_{t_{new}}$ is no longer a static Killing vector field, obviously, and the metric in these coordinates is not explicitly time-independent.